# Can I migrate users locally stored CoreData to a server later on?

Tags: swift, core-data, server, swiftui, core-data-migration

As with many other founders and their start-ups, I'm low on cash and aiming to launch without funding. The app will be dealing with users health data so setting up a server with the correct encryption may be costly. I am also only familiar with JSON, SwiftUI, Swift5 and API programming so setting up a server is outside my scope of expertise.

Therefore, I aim to launch the app with all user data stored locally in SwiftUI CoreData, as to avoid these issues. With enough users i.e. traction, I will then begin to seek funding, at which point I would hope to set up an encrypted server and transfer user data there.

I am worried that if I launch with local storage, I will not be able to transfer each individual users data to an external server, without them having to reenter all of their information.

I was just wondering whether this was possible or not? And if you could provide details that would be very helpful.

Comment: Your app will have the ability to read this data, correct? Why could it not, in the future, read the data and push it to a server? Technically, there is no reason you can't do this.

However, there may be legal reasons. You'll have to divulge to users in your ToS that this is happening. Further, if you're making a health app on iOS, make sure you understand Apple's Health APIs and developer requirements.

Comment: Do you know about CloudKit?

Comment: Adding onto matt's comment, Xcode has a template for CoreData app that has CloudKit. It works just like CoreData, the cloud bit is handled in the background. As long as you have an Apple Developer Account you can get started without any servers!

Comment: @Shon thank you, yes I am aware of the legal issues (and subsequent costs) surrounding storage of users health data in an external server which is why upon launch I plan to just use local core data